# How to automatic run asp.net mvc project in background process without open it in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have build a project in ASP.net MVC platform. Now i want to run it windows startup process without open browse.
i am running this project by click start button of my application,then the process of the project start. But I want this project to be hosted on IIS server and run automatically in the background without open in browser and click on the start button.

**Controller:**

```
namespace FaceCompare.Controllers

public class FaceCompareController : Controller
{
    // GET: FaceCompare
    public ActionResult Index()
    {          
        var inlist = FaceMatchInList();
        var outlist = FaceMatchOutList();  
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FaceCompare()
    {
        var inlist = FaceMatchInList();
        var outlist = FaceMatchOutList();  
        return View();
    }
    public List<FaceCompareModel> FaceMatchInList()
    {
        string[] filePaths = null;
        DateTime foldertime = DateTime.Now;
        string folderdatelocation = foldertime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/FolderLocation/CapImgLoaction.txt");

        string FolderLocation;
        string myString;
        using (StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(path))
        {

            FolderLocation = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string location1path = Server.MapPath("~/FolderLocation/location1.txt");
            string location1;
            string location1String;
            using (StreamReader location1reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(location1path))
            {
                location1 = location1reader.ReadToEnd();
                location1String = location1.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
            }

            string location2path = Server.MapPath("~/FolderLocation/location2.txt");
            string location2;
            string location2String;
            using (StreamReader location2reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(location2path))
            {
                location2 = location2reader.ReadToEnd();
                location2String = location2.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
            }   

            Rijndael128EncryptorDAO rnDAO = new Rijndael128EncryptorDAO();
            string decrypt = rnDAO.AES_decrypt(FolderLocation, location1String, location2String);

            myString = decrypt.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
        }

        string INIPAddressPath = Server.MapPath("~/FolderLocation/INCameraIPAddress.txt");
        string INCameraIPAddress;
        string INCameraIPAddressmyString;
        using (StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(INIPAddressPath))
        {
            INCameraIPAddress = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string location1path = Server.MapPath("~/FolderLocation/location1.txt");
            string location1;
            string location1String;
            using (StreamReader location1reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(location1path))
            {
                location1 = location1reader.ReadToEnd();
                location1String = location1.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
            }

            string location2path = Server.MapPath("~/FolderLocation/location2.txt");
            string location2;
            string location2String;
            using (StreamReader location2reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(location2path))
            {
                location2 = location2reader.ReadToEnd();
                location2String = location2.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
            }

            Rijndael128EncryptorDAO rnDAO = new Rijndael128EncryptorDAO();
            string decrypt = rnDAO.AES_decrypt(INCameraIPAddress, location1String, location2String);
            INCameraIPAddressmyString = decrypt.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
        }   
       
        try
        {
            filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(myString + "\\" + folderdatelocation + "\\" + INCameraIPAddressmyString + "\\" + "CompOk", "*_SRC.JPG*");
        }
```

**View**
i don't want to user by click start button in browser.It will auto start in background without open browser.

@using (Html.BeginForm("FaceCompare", "FaceCompare", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "showLoader(this);" }))

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
        <h2 class="text-center">Image To Compare</h2>
        <table border="1" width=100%>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Sl. no.</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Images</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Start" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some more details about the problem. If you want a background job you can create a Windows Service application (in .Net) and configure to run it as a Windows service. You do not need IIS to run it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have add details overview, please check it once again.